# Is it possible to set up a Angular TestBed inside of a Playwright spec file?

Tags: angular, jasmine, playwright

So I have a weird test case where I'm trying to use Playwright.js and Angular's TestBed together.

I need to change the component instance in the browser so I can write two different assertions.

One to check if a DOM element is not visible when the browser is at a certain height and another to verify that it's there.

But the DOM element is controlled by Angular. So I was hoping to use the TestBed to create a Fixture of the component like a normal Jasmine test and then switch the button on and off that way.

This file is then run by Playwright.js using the Protractor configuration in Angular. Playwright works fine and runs simple DOM tests but I need it to test for a component change. `jasmine-playwright.e2e-spec`

This is what I have so far which as you might guess does not work.

```
import { chromium, Browser, Page } from 'playwright';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

import { AppComponent } from '../../src/app/app.component';

fdescribe('Testing an Angular Component in Playwright app', () => {

  let browser: Browser;
  let page: Page;

  let component: AppComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let el: DebugElement;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 2000 });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:4200');

    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations:[AppComponent],
      imports:[],
      providers: []
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(()=>{
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        el = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      })

  });

  it('Jasmine Should not be the correct page title', async () => {
    expect(await page.title()).not.toBe('This  doesn't work');
  });


  afterAll(async () => {
    await browser.close();
  });
});
```

Right now all I get is

```
- Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
```

which hasn't been very helpful.

Comment: Is there any luck with TestBed + playwright approach?

Comment: None. I gave up after while. I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the problem on my side I realized that playwright is a library running on node (a server), while TestBed is API that runs directly in the browser (a client). So, you should not mix them in a single function.

This means that for unit test scenarios I should continue use Karma that runs purely in browser and does not depend on protractor nor selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout my library for component testing with Angular and Playwright: https://github.com/sand4rt/playwright-ct-angular. It uses TestBed under the hood. See example below:

```js
// button.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'button-component',
  template: `<button>{{title}}</button>`,
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() title!: string;
}
```

```js
// button.component.test.ts
import { test, expect } from '@sand4rt/experimental-ct-angular';
import { ButtonComponent } from './components/button.component';

test('render props', async ({ mount }) => {
  const component = await mount(ButtonComponent, {
    props: {
      title: 'Submit',
    },
  });
  await expect(component).toContainText('Submit');
});
```